# Triaging iOS kernel panic related to sockets

Tags: ios, c, sockets, kernel, panic

I have an iOS app that does alot of low-level socket work, and recently after adding IPv6 support I noticed there is a kernel panic which occurs sometimes when running my app. The entire device reboots, and I get a panic file which has alot of cryptic information (including no stack frames from my app), but a few critical things as shown here:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800f15fba0): assertion failed: se->se_flags & SEF_ATTACHED, file: /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2784.30.7/bsd/kern/uipc_socket.c, line:     6228
Debugger message: panic
```

Fortunately this module is open source, and I found the code for a close version here: http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-2782.1.97/bsd/kern/uipc_socket.c

The error seems to match up with this function:

```
void
sockaddrlist_remove(struct sockaddr_list *sl, struct sockaddr_entry *se)
{
    VERIFY(se->se_flags & SEF_ATTACHED);
    se->se_flags &= ~SEF_ATTACHED;
    VERIFY(sl->sl_cnt != 0);
    sl->sl_cnt--;
    TAILQ_REMOVE(&sl->sl_head, se, se_link);
}
```

I'm pretty sure the first VERIFY(), which is basically an assert, is failing.

However, this just tells me that some memory was probably corrupted by my program some time before this code got to run. So, like most memory corruptions, it is very challenging to find the cause.

Based on my logging, I see this happen after roughly some networking calls, including socket(), connect(), read() and write(), though it wouldn't be feasible to give the code here.

Another piece of information is this only happens with IPv6. On IPv4, everything works without issue. But I have scrubbed the IPv6 code and have not found anything obviously wrong. Also I'm confused how any memory corruption issue in user space would make the kernel fail. Maybe understanding how this could happen would help me trace the issue.

The next step most people would say is to try the guard malloc, however unfortunately when I try to turn that on I run into another problem, so for now lets just make the assumption that I cannot use guard malloc at present.

I have also tried to attach to the program live while running and make it crash, but it doesn't stop in the debugger anywhere, it just reboots the entire device (iPad).

If anyone has any triaging ideas for this tricky bug, please let me know.

EDIT:

Based on the feedback from one of the answers, I've checked all the lengths for the relevant socket API calls and those seem to be correct. So it seems like there is some other issue here, possibly overwriting memory.

I was able to try using "Malloc Guard Edges", but then the problem stops happening. I can't use "Guard Malloc" since it will only work on the simulator, and my app doesn't run well on the simulator due to how it interacts with the hardware.

If anyone has any more ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Log it with Apple and use one of your `TSI`s?: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may try that, but since those are limited (or cost money to get more), I'd like to exhaust all other ideas first.

Comment: If you can cause a panic from user mode, it's a kernel bug. Report it.

Comment: At present I can only do this from 8.x, though I haven't tested extensively on iOS 9 yet. So even if I report this I don't think apple will be fixing it. However, I want to make sure my users using 8.x don't see crashes, so I want to try and fix it. Even though it is technically an apple bug, it is also a bug in my code since before I added my latest changes (to support IPv6) this didn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happen (improperly coded IPv6 changes in iOS app causing the entire phone to reboot).

In my case, it was caused by making the system call `sendto()` with the wrong `dest_len`, one that didn't match the size of the structure pointed to by `dest_addr`. This kind of issue is possible to come up when adding support for IPv6 because, when everything was IPv4, all `sockaddr` structures are `sockaddr_in`, with the same size which can be hard-coded, but when you can have IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, you can have different-sized structures, and you have to pass the correct length corresponding to the structure passed. Your particular issue might not be exactly in `sendto()`, but it might be a similar issue so I would check every system call where you need to pass a `socklen_t`, including `bind()` and `connect()`.

I agree that no code in the app should be able to cause the phone to reboot, and that the fact that this is possible is an Apple bug.

Although it is not possible for the debugger to stop on a kernel panic (because the device disconnects, so the debugger stops), you can still debug it in a way, if you know approximately where it happens, you can step line-by-line in the debugger, and see which line it kernel panics at. The line it panics on will be a function call (the panic happens inside the call), so you can now step inside that function call, and repeat, until you've narrowed it down to the specific system call.

Comment: Thanks very much for the hint about incorrect length being a possibility. I actually already had a bug like that, but there may be more lying around. Regarding your last paragraph however, based on my original post I think I know what line it is panicking at, but that is just because the state of a socket-related variable is not what it should be. I thought that the panic could be arbitrarily apart in time and code from the actual cause.

Comment: One followup question: Everytime I pass a "struct sockaddr_storage" to a function like bind(), using X.ss_len should be correct for the length, right?

Comment: @Locksleyu: Well in my case the problem was with the arguments to the system call, so knowing where it panics is useful. Are you saying that your problem is with something other than the arguments to the system call?

Comment: @Locksleyu: Yes, it should be okay to use the length field of the structure, as long as you know for sure that all the places where you get the structure from do set the length field. However, cross-platform code might not set this field, as many platforms don't have this field.

Comment: Regarding your previous comment: Yes, I would guess that the problem is related to the arguments to a system call, though I don't know 100%. However, since the actual panic is occurring in the kernel, away from any of my code, and it is also happening during what looks like some free-type behavior (removing something from a list), I am not sure if the debugger will directly help narrow down where the cause is. For you I think it crashed immediately during a system call, but for it is within a kernel call, and my app is not listed in any of the stacks in the kernel panic dump.

Comment: @Locksleyu: But if you can catch the phone rebooting while stepping line-by-line through some function, then you can narrow down exactly where in your app's code the reboot happens. That's what I was saying.

Comment: Yeah, that would be ideal. I'll do some experimentation. But the panic report seems to imply that during the actual reboot none of my code is running.